# Is it possible to restrict int value (set a range) using bitwise operations?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I need to have my integer counter have values from 1 to 6 inclusive in wrap around fashion. Namely starting from 1, I count to 6 and go back to 1. I wonder if it's possible to achieve using some sort of bitwise logic. Of course it's trivial with if statement as below but I am wondering about one liner :)

```
int counter = 1;

for...
    do something
    if (counter++ == 7) counter = 1;
```

Addition:
Here is why I want 1 liner:

```
byte output = (byte)((inputByte & 0xF8) | counter++);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use bitwise logic for something like this? What would that give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulo operator.

```
do something;    
++counter; counter %= 7; ++counter;
```

To use *real* bitwise operations your modulo must be a power-of-2 which is not the case here.

PS: If your counter started at 0 instead of 1, you wouldn't need the second `++counter` and would write something like :

```
for (int counter = 0; (somecondition); ++counter, counter %= 7)
{
    do something;
}
```

PPS: Note that generally an `if` performs faster than a modulo, tho.

Comment: It should work. Here is why I want 1 liner: `byte output = (byte)((inputByte & 0xF8) | counter++);` So it becomes then `byte output = (byte)((inputByte & 0xF8) | (++counter % 7));`. Is modulo fast?